# Regular expression works normally, but fails when placed in an XML schema

Tags: python, regex, validation, schema, lxml

I have a simple `doc.xml` file which contains a single root element with a Timestamp attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root Timestamp="04-21-2010 16:00:19.000" />
```

I'd like to validate this document against a my simple `schema.xsd` to make sure that the Timestamp is in the correct format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="Timestamp" use="required" type="timeStampType"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="timeStampType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="(0[0-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1})-(3[0-1]{1}|[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1})-[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3} ([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1}):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{3}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

So I use the [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) Python module and try to perform a simple schema validation and report any errors:

```
from lxml import etree

schema = etree.XMLSchema( etree.parse("schema.xsd") )
doc = etree.parse("doc.xml")

if not schema.validate(doc):
    for e in schema.error_log:
        print e.message
```

My XML document fails validation with the following error messages:

```
Element 'root', attribute 'Timestamp': [facet 'pattern'] The value '04-21-2010 16:00:19.000' is not accepted by the pattern '(0[0-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1})-(3[0-1]{1}|[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1})-[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3} ([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1}):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{3}'.
Element 'root', attribute 'Timestamp': '04-21-2010 16:00:19.000' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'timeStampType'.
```

So it looks like my regular expression must be faulty.  But when I try to validate the regular expression at the command line, it passes:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = '(0[0-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1})-(3[0-1]{1}|[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1})-[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3} ([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1}):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{3}'
>>> assert re.match(pat, '04-21-2010 16:00:19.000')
>>>
```

I'm aware that XSD regular expressions don't have every feature, but [the documentation I've found](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) indicates that every feature that I'm using should work.

So what am I mis-understanding, and why does my document fail?

Comment: Off topic: any reason for the '{1}'s? Since atoms match exactly once, they seem redundant.

Comment: @outis: Yes, they are redundant and should be removed.  All they do is make the regex harder to read, and Lord knows regexes don't need any help in that regard!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `|`s match wider than you think.

```
(0[0-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1})-(3[0-1]{1}|[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1})-[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}
```

is parsed as:

```
(0[0-9]{1})
    -or-
(1[0-2]{1})-(3[0-1]{1}|[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1})-[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}
```

You need to use more groupings if you want to avoid it; e.g.

```
((0[0-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1}))-((3[0-1]{1}|[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}))-[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3} (([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1})):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{3}
```

Comment: That's the reason it's failing to match valid input, but the revised regex can still match a lot of invalid input, as @Daniel points out.

Comment: Well yeah, but that was his question :)

Answer (score 3):

The expression has several errors.

1. You allow `00` as a valid month.
2. `A|BC` matches `A` and `BC` - not `AC` and `BC`. Hence your expression starting with `(0[0-9]{1})|` matches any string containing `00` through `09`. What you want is `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-` only matching `01` through `12` followed by a dash.
3. You allow `00` as a valid day.
4. The pattern is not anchored to the beginning and end of the text - add `^` and `$`. That is why your test using Python succeeded.

By the way - why don't you use `xs:dateTime`? It has a very similar format - `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fff` I think.

Comment: To elaborate on point #4: the Python regex should have *added* anchors to mimic the behavior of XSD regexes, which are implicitly anchored.  (Also, the `.` near the end should be `\.`.)  But as you said, with `xs:dateTime` available, this is probably all academic anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the points and suggestions about `xs:dateTime` - as it is, I've been handed a schema and xml doc written by someone else and am just trying to figure out how to make them pass with a minimum of changes, but I'll definitely remember the `xs:dateTime` type for when I next construct a schema myself.